# Minimax algorithm tic tac toe error

Tags: java, recursion, artificial-intelligence, tic-tac-toe, minimax

```
at TicTacToe.minvalue(TicTacToe.java:184)
    at TicTacToe.maxvalue(TicTacToe.java:197)
    at TicTacToe.minvalue(TicTacToe.java:184)
    at TicTacToe.maxvalue(TicTacToe.java:197)
    at TicTacToe.minvalue(TicTacToe.java:184)
    at TicTacToe.maxvalue(TicTacToe.java:197)
    at TicTacToe.minvalue(TicTacToe.java:184)
    at TicTacToe.maxvalue(TicTacToe.java:197)
    at TicTacToe.minvalue(TicTacToe.java:184)
    at TicTacToe.maxvalue(TicTacToe.java:197)
    at TicTacToe.minvalue(TicTacToe.java:184)
```

I cannot see the error since it's so long.
Here are the functions maxValue()and minValue()

```
 private int minvalue(char [] brd){
    int m = (int) Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int v;
    for(int a : actions(brd)){
        char [] nextbrd = result(brd, a, human);
        if(status(nextbrd)=='C') v = maxvalue(nextbrd); //line 184
        else v = utility(nextbrd);
        m = Math.min(m, v);

    }
    return m;
}

private int maxvalue(char [] brd){
    int m = (int) Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int v;
    for(int a : actions(brd)){
        char [] nextbrd = result(brd, a, agent);
        if(status(nextbrd)=='C') v = minvalue(nextbrd); //line 189
        else v = utility(nextbrd);
        if(v==Math.max(m, v))   nextAction = a;
        m = Math.max(m, v);

    }
    return m;
}
```

utility function() just returns 1 if the winner is the agent. -1 otherwise.
status returns 'C' if the game is not yet over.
I dont know what's wrong.

UPDATE: I changed the m in the maxValue() function to MIN_VALUE but I still get the same error.

Comment: is this full code? can you add full code

Comment: You need to post the Exception. Scroll up in your output.

Comment: I see one error, for finding Max and min both u are using Integer.MAX_VALUE,  for max it shud be Integer.MIN_VALUE;

Comment: Looks like you are getting StackOverflow error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214741/what-is-a-stackoverflowerror

Answer (score 1):

Once your code reach the `maxvalue` method you will get an `StackOverflow` error as your `nextAction` value will never change again.
The condition to change nextAction is shown as

```
if(v==Math.max(m, v))   nextAction = a;
```

But at the beginning you have initialized

```
int m = (int) Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

So the `if` statement will never be true as per your code.
The following correction looks the obvious approach to avoid `StackOverflow` error.

```
   private int maxvalue(char [] brd){
    int m = (int) Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int v;
    for(int a : actions(brd)){
        char [] nextbrd = result(brd, a, agent);
        if(status(nextbrd)=='C') v = minvalue(nextbrd); //line 189
        else v = utility(nextbrd);
        if(v==Math.max(m, v))   nextAction = a;
        m = Math.max(m, v);

    }
    return m;
}
```

Comment: I changed it to MIN.VALUE but it still produces the same error